# Encrypted HFS+ on Windows

Tags: windows

I've been trying to open an encrypted (FileVault 2) HFS+ external hard disk on Windows 7. Since all the software available seem not able to do it, I've tried by installing the bootcamp drivers on Windows. First manually (placing `AppleHFS.sys` and `AppleMNT.sys` into `system32/drivers` and adding the proper regedit keys) and then, since this didn't work, using the whole bootcamp installer. When I connect the drive, it's still unrecognized (even in the Drive Manager). What should I do? (or maybe: is it possible?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple's BootCamp drivers do not have the driver or other software support needed to mount a volume using FileVault 2's encryption (otherwise known as CoreStorage encryption.)

To the best of my knowledge, there's no way to unlock and mount a CoreStorage encrypted volume on any OS except by using a Mac running Mac OS X 10.7.x.

Comment: Thank you. :) I'll just give up and share another disk. :P